# Studying the convergence of integral alone (ratio: zero/zero)

Tags: convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

I am looking for an examination of the convergence of the integral alone:
$$\int_0^2 \frac {\sqrt{2-x}\,dx} {x^2-5x+6}$$

Any way to prove the convergence without calculation of the integral?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: This integral is equal to
$$\int_0^2\frac1{(3-x)\sqrt{2-x}}dx$$

Comment: Well, agree, I could apply substitution u=3-x to calculate it. But how to prove convergence without calculation?

Comment: For $x$ near $2$ this integrand is equivalent to $\frac1{\sqrt{2-x}}$ which converges when integrated for $0\le x\le2$. There is no issue with the integrand at $x=0$. So, the integrand and hence the integral is finite and converges.